# @Bindable property not found

Tags: android, android-databinding

Basically, i have the following class:

```
class SignInRequest: BaseObservable() {

    @Bindable
    var email: String = ""
        set(value) {
            field = value
            notifyPropertyChanged(BR.email)
        }

    @Bindable
    var password: String = ""
        set(value) {
            field = value
            notifyPropertyChanged(BR.password)
        }
}
```

When i focus on `BR.email` i get `Unresolved reference: email` (same for `BR.password`). Weirdly though, if i open the autogenerated BR class, those variables are there. Also the project builds correctly and the application runs as exepected. It's just that for some reason Android Studio cannot access those variables.

This is my module `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "it.fisbapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    // DEFAULT
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'

    // FIREBASE
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-play-services:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0'

    // DAGGER 2
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.22.1'
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.22.1'
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.22.1'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.22.1'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.22.1'

    // KOTLIN ARROW
    implementation "io.arrow-kt:arrow-core-data:0.9.0"

    // ARCHITECTURE COMPONENTS
    kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:3.2.0-alpha10"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.1.0'
    kapt 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:2.1.0'
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.1.0-alpha04"
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Gradle version: 5.4.1

Android Studio version (for Linux): 3.5.3

**EDIT**

I forgot to mention that i've already tried to clean and rebuild the project, and invalidate cache and restart.

Layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <data>
        <variable name="viewModel" type="it.fisbapp.ui.welcome.viewmodel.SignInViewModel"/>
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".ui.welcome.fragment.SignInFragment">

        <ScrollView
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="70dp">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="24dp"
                    android:id="@+id/guideline_left"/>

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/guideline_right"
                    app:layout_constraintGuide_end="24dp"/>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/email"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:hint="@string/sign_in_layout_edit_text_email_hint"
                    android:text="@={viewModel.signInRequest.email}"
                    app:error="@{viewModel.signInRequest.emailError}"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline_right"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline_left"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/password"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:hint="@string/sign_in_layout_edit_text_password_hint"
                    android:text="@={viewModel.signInRequest.password}"
                    app:error="@{viewModel.signInRequest.passwordError}"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/email"
                    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline_right"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline_left"/>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/signIn"
                    android:text="@string/sign_in_layout_button_sign_in"
                    android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.onSignIn()}"
                    app:gone="@{safeUnbox(viewModel.isLoading)}"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/password"
                    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline_right"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline_left"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/gotoSignUp"
                    android:text="@string/sign_in_layout_label_sign_up"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline_right"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline_left"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/signIn"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.onGotoSignUp()}"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/gotoForgotPwd"
                    android:text="@string/sign_in_layout_label_reset_password"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline_right"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline_left"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/gotoSignUp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.onGotoResetPwd()}"/>

                <ProgressBar
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline_right"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline_left"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/gotoForgotPwd"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    app:visible="@{safeUnbox(viewModel.isLoading)}"/>

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        </ScrollView>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```

ViewModel:

```
class SignInViewModel(val authRepository: AuthRepository): BaseViewModel() {

    val signInRequest = SignInRequest()
    val onSignin = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
    val onError = MutableLiveData<String>()
    val onGotoSignUp = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
    val onGotoResetPwd = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
    val isLoading = MutableLiveData<Boolean>().apply { postValue(false) }

    fun onSignIn() {
        isLoading.postValue(true)
        viewModelScope.launch {
            if(signInRequest.isValid()) {
                val email = signInRequest.email
                val pwd = signInRequest.password
                authRepository
                    .signIn(email, pwd)
                    .fold(
                        ifLeft = { onError.postValue(it.errMsg) },
                        ifRight = { onSignin.postValue(true) }
                    )
            }
            isLoading.postValue(false)
        }
    }

    fun onGotoSignUp() {
        onGotoSignUp.postValue(true)
    }

    fun onGotoResetPwd() {
        onGotoResetPwd.postValue(true)
    }

}
```

Comment: in your case, I believe there should be a problem with xml layout in which you are binding the attribute `email` and `password`. Can you post the corresponding xml file as well?

Comment: Sure. The layout seems ok to me. Also the application runs correctly, so i guess it's related to Android Studio that for some reason cannot access build folder.

Answer (score 0):

You need to mention the sme variables in your layout file corresponding attributes.
This is the actual flow of data binding. So that your layouts nd model nd viewmodel can interact with eachother.

Comment: Well, maybe I'm wrong, but it seems to me that it is a fairly common pattern to declare the viewmodel as a variable within the layout, and access viewmodel's variables (LiveData, ObservableProperty etc) through databinding

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to replace this line :

```
kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:3.2.0-alpha10"
```

with this :

```
kapt 'com.android.databinding:compiler:3.1.4'
```

Also alternative you can try with ObservableField.

```
public class User {
public static ObservableField<String> name = new ObservableField<>();
public static ObservableField<String> email = new ObservableField<>();

public ObservableField<String> getName() {
    return name;
}

public ObservableField<String> getEmail() {
    return email;
}
}
```

Comment: Replacing the dependecy didn't work, and regarding the ObservableField, yeah, it should work. But I'd rather understand why the current implementation isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Likely it won't build while `BR` won't resolve - but `BR` should resolve, once it successfully built ...

Try to comment out `// notifyPropertyChanged()` build the project and then un-comment it again.

And I think you can remove `com.android.databinding:compiler:3.2.0-alpha10` altogether, because configuration `dataBinding {enabled = true}` adds all the dependencies it needs.

Comment: I commented the `notifyPropertyChanged()` and `@Bindable` annotation, builded and the variable was gone from the autogenerated BR class. Uncommented, rebuilded and it was back in. Everything works as expected, except that android studio reports an error that does not exist.